# How do I raise the vertical height of an exponent in a math equation even higher?

Tags: math-mode

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
    
    \(
    \bigintss\frac{x^{\frac{x}{2\ln{x}}}}{\sqrt{e^{x}}}\dd{x}
    \)
    
\end{document}
```

The outcome:
[image]

The exponent is barely above the vinculum and it doesn't really look very nice! I belive brackets will not really help if the exponent stays so low. How can I raise it?

Comment: Wouldn't `\(\int dx\)` be simpler to write?

Comment: @egreg I assume that this is an exercise and the students are supposed to find this simplification themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For inline math, the exponent is not so high, in an attempt avoid messing up the uniform line spacing of the document.  However, if that is no object, then one can place the exponent relative, not to the `x`, but to a taller `\strut`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
    
    \(
    \bigintss\frac{x\strut^{\frac{x}{2\ln{x}}}}{\sqrt{e^{x}}}\dd{x}
    \)
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

To lower the `x` a bit in this circumstance, one could define a custom `\mystrut`, that only takes the height of a strut, but discards the depth of it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{physics}
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}}
\begin{document}
    \(
    \bigintss\frac{x\mystrut^{\frac{x}{2\ln{x}}}}{\sqrt{e^{x}}}\dd{x}
    \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. What does strut mean though? (I also should've specified in my question that the exponent was still low in display mode as well)

Comment: @user71207 A `\strut` is a non-visible entity that has zero width, but spans the full vertical height between lines of text (thus it has total height of `\baselineskip`).  If you want to "see" a strut temporarily, you can `\newcommand\visiblestrut{\bgroup\fboxrule=.1pt \fboxsep=-\fboxrule \fbox{\strut}\egroup}` and replace the `\strut` in my code with `\visiblestrut`.

Comment: You probably want `\mathstrut`, because `\strut` depends on the `\baselineskip` of the surrounding paragraph.

Comment: @HenriMenke I hear you, but `\mathstrut` puts it right back where the OP doesn't like.